# Unable to install Signal from App Store on iPhone

Tags: applications, error, signal

I had been using Signal on my phone for a week. last night it stopped working and i was not able to send messages. I tried uninstalling and when i installed it again it does not install. it throws an error.

Can someone help me with this error

> "This operation couldn't be completed"
> (SignalServiceKit.NetworkManagerError error 504.)

Answer (score 1):

Signal is/was down today, maybe just wait til they are back up. You can check the current state on the [Signal Status Page](https://status.signal.org/).

From https://twitter.com/signalapp/status/1350118809860886528?s=20

> Signal is experiencing technical difficulties. We are working hard to restore service as quickly as possible.